# Kial praavo venas de iu lando, anstataŭ "venis"?

Tags: translation

> Saluton. Duolingo diras: "Mia praavo venas el Ĉinio."

1. Kial oni diras la frazon kun "venas", anstataŭ "venis"? (Estas klara ke la praavo venis antaŭ multaj jaroj)
2. La traduko de la frazo en l'angla estas: My great-grandfather "comes" from China. Do, ĉu tio estas laŭ iu speciala metodo en l'angla por priparoli malnovegajn tempojn?

Comment: Kial kaj kiel "estas klara ke la praavo venis antaŭ multaj jaroj"?

Answer (score 3):

Kiam oni uzas *veni* en tiaj frazoj, oni ofte priskribas la originon. (Samsignifa vorto por [*origino*](http://vortaro.net/#origino) estas *deveno*).

Se la praavo ankoraŭ vivas, lia origino ne ŝanĝiĝis nek ŝanĝiĝos kaj plu estAS *el Ĉinio*. Pro tio vi devus uzi la *-as* formon.

Ankaŭ vi povus uzi la *-as* formon dum iom da tempo post la alveno. La daŭro de veno estas tamen subjektiva; dum li serĉas loĝejon en la nova lando oni povus diri ke li ankoraŭ ne plene alvenis, kaj do plu diri *li venAS el Ĉinio*.

Se la alveno okazis antaŭ tre longe, se la praavo mortis aŭ se vi celas la faktan translokiĝon (sed **ne** lian originon), vi devus uzi la *-is* formon.

Comment: Eduardo pravas pri la verbo mem kaj pri la tempo. Pli bone estus uzi la verbon "[deveni de/el](http://vortaro.net/#deveni)" (← veni de iu loko), sed multaj uzas la simplan "veni de/el iu loko".

Comment: Dankon pro via klarigo, Sinjoro Trápani. Mi pensis ke tio estas laŭvorta tradukaĵo de iu idiomaĵo en l'angla. Mi pensis ke Anglalingvanoj diras "My great-grandfather comes from China" por indiki ke li venis el Ĉinio antaŭ multaj jaroj, ekzemple, en la 19a jarcento (tamen mi nek parolas l'anglan flue, nek certas ĉu Anglalingvanoj verdire diras tielmaniere aŭ ne).

Comment: Ankaŭ dankon al vi, Sinjoro Metsäkallas, pro proponi la verbon "deveni de/el".

Answer (score 0):

> La familio, parencaro de mia avo originas el Ĉinio.

En tiu frazo la ***sentempa*** `-as` estas klara. Por unu specifa persono, kaj precipe la verbo `ven-` oni povus pensi pri konkreta momento en historio, `per ŝipo`.

Same validus, se oni uzus la preteriton en la angla: `came`.

Alimaniere `du plus du egalas al kvar`; `egalis` kaj `egalos`. Same la praavo *originas* el Ĉinio kaj en la estonteco neniam subite *origin**o**s* el alia lando. (Kontraŭe al iu epidemio kiu povus ŝanĝi sian originon.)